# I can't read env values in mikro-orm.config.ts

Tags: configuration, nest, mikro-orm

I use mikro-orm in nest js, and i write mikro-orm.config.ts with using configService.get().
But it doesn't get env value. Process.env is too.
In other files like main.ts, it can get env properly, but not in mikro-orm.config.ts.
How should i get it?

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { Options } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { SqlHighlighter } from '@mikro-orm/sql-highlighter';

const configService = new ConfigService();

const logger = new Logger('MikroORM');
const MikroORMConfig: Options = {
  dbName: process.env.POSTGRES_DATABASE == '' ? 'database' : 'database',
  user: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.POSTGRES_PORT),
  type: 'postgresql',
  entities: ['./dist/**/*.entity.js'],
  entitiesTs: ['./src/**/*.entity.ts'],
  highlighter: new SqlHighlighter(),
  migrations: {
    path: './src/feature/database/migrations',
  },
  logger: logger.log.bind(logger),
};
export default MikroORMConfig;
```

I use process.env and configService but both of them didn't get env.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use anything from nestjs for the CLI config, the CLI is not aware of such a thing. Where do you define the env vars? I guess some `.env` file? The ORM will try to read that automatically, but only if it's in the root of your project (and named exactly `.env`).

If the `.env` file is elsewhere or named differently, you could register it in your CLI config:

```
import 'dotenv/config'; // or require('dotenv').config()
import { defineConfig } from '@mikro-orm/postgresql';

export default defineConfig({ ... }); // also prefer using `defineConfig`
```